# Cassandra data-model to perform column sorting?

Tags: database, jdbc, cassandra, data-modeling

I have the following use case for a music service app I am working on (back end cassandra).

My music datastore will have artist, genre, year,the song name, number of views, track length, byte encoded content. I want to be able to filter by artist; artist and genre; artist, genre and year. Also I want the song names to appear as descending sorted by number views.

I have the following table:

```
MusicStore (
  artist text,
  genre text,  
  year text,
  songName text,
  views bigint
  tracklenght bigint,
  content text,

  PRIMARY KEY ((artist), genre, year, views, songName))
  WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (year DESC, views DESC, songName ASC);
```

The immediate problem I am running into:

In my app where I allow search by artist and genre:

```
select * from MusicStore  where artist='alizee' AND genre='pop' order by views
```

This query does not work. It says "Orderby currently only supports the ordering of columns following their declared orders in primary key".

It seems orderby is only allowed on the first clustering key.Anything I am missing?

Denormalization is possible for couple use cases, but I will run into the same issue for my app to search artist by genre and year since Cassandra requires where clause keys to be present in primary key and in the same order as the query (genre, then year) and views column being the first clustering key is not possible.  Making views first clustering key would require everything else being partition key and therefore mandatory in the where clause.

Any suggestions on the datamodel? Is there anyway I can avoid this by using column family (with supercolumns) using thrift API?

Answer (score 2):

Clustering keys are applied left to right - if you supply artist and genre in the WHERE, you can sort on year (ascending, descending, equal, or inequalities - >, <, >=, <= ).

If you also provide year, you can then sort by views (ascending, descending, equal, or inequalities).

You do NOT want to use supercolumns, and the thrift API is more difficult to understand for most users. There's no easy magic there, the sorting is what it is (based on sstable format), and thrift is bound by the same limitations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To fulfill my use cases to filter by genre and year (and sorted by views), is there any alternative data-model approach? Denormalization will not help here I think since I have to have the clustering keys in the right order for the where clause query.

Comment: To me it seems a pretty trivial functionality any database engine should support (to be able to order columns). Coming from RDBMS world, cassandra seems to lack this basic feature or I am just missing something in my data-model?

Comment: Cassandra isn't an RDBMS. Cassandra is designed for the use case where you have potentially a thousand servers, each of which holding potentially terabytes of data. It makes sacrifices to reach that scale - you can't arbitrarily sort any field you want. It allows you to sort on clustering keys, because clustering keys determine the order each cell is written on disk. Sorting then becomes a seek to the start (or end) of that area on disk, and walking in the direction of the read. If you wanted to sort on views without limiting year, you'd be skip through and across dozens or hundreds of files